Safari passwords autofill and 1password autofill clashing and overlapping
If I use both Safari passwords and 1password (and I don't need to justify yourself for using both at the same time), I am faced with overlapping controls and windows when wanting to select a password, one covering the other.
You can see similar discussions at 1password support: https://1password.community/discussion/126533/safari-dropdown-overlaps-1password-dropdown


In Safari advanced settings, you can set a custom style sheet.
Just create a css file on your mac, where you want and put:
#op-menu {
    margin-top: -200px !important;
}

Or
#op-menu {
    margin-left: 300px !important;
}

Or whatever css you'd want, but this works, it will move the window up the fields instead of down, not so pretty, but working!
